# Could not initialize LoginButton Facebook-sdk for android

Tags: android, xml, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

im working on an android project an i want to put a Facebook Login feature, i added the Facebook sdk Correctly but i could not initialize LoginButton

```
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class       com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton**
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:413)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:176)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:400)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:708)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:697)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:697)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:816)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**here is my AppManifest.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".helloActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_hello" >
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
</application>
```

**I specified the App_id in Strings.xml. 
Thanks for help**

Comment: Have you added a library (probably a jar file) to your project?

Comment: Yes i added Facebook properly PS : im working on Android Studio

Comment: Well, the error suggests that the library is not actually there.

Comment: Same error! I cannot inflate the layout because of this. Have you come across the solution yet?

Comment: Did anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 18):

This is due to non-initialization of FacebookSdk before its usage.
Just add below line:

`FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(mContext);`

in case host of LoginButton is:

1.Activity- before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

2.Fragment- before `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)`

Also don't forget to listen the callback in `onActivityResult()` in above cases to update the UI of `LoginButton`.

Comment: I'm getting this error on the xml preview (Works fine when compiled). Any clues what might be causing it

Comment: @feresr What preview API are you using ? By default it shows the latest one, but for API 22 the layout show errors : Try changing the Preview API to 21

Answer (score 4):

I checked on latest SDK4.0.1, in that com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton is available. But this was not found in facebook-android-sdk-3.17.1, there we have only com.facebook.widget.LoginButton available. Facebook didn't notified the developers or in their changelogs that LoginButton class moved to sub folder.

Very strange why facebook not updating correctly..  Even the [doc for Android login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.0) is wrong!!

Comment: Facebook Documentation sucks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you *Manifest.xml*

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName" android:value="@string/app_name" />
```