# The following classes could not be instantiated: – com.facebook.widget.LoginButton

Tags: android, facebook

I have been working on getting the Facebook practice apps working and I cannot figure out why I cannot reference the `LoginButton` found in the Facebook SDK. Below is the error that I am encountering when I look at the layout that defines the `LoginButton`.

```
 <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton   at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at
org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:413)
        at
org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
        at
com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:176)
        at
android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
        at
android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
        at
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at
android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)    at
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)    at
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)    at
com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:400)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
        at
com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
        at
com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:708)
        at
com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$5.compute(RenderService.java:697)
        at
com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
        at
com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:697)
        at
com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:816)
        at
com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
        at
com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
        at
com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
        at
com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
        at
com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
        at
com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
        at
com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
        at
com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
        at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)    at
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Which Facebook SDK version are you using?

Comment: 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'

Comment: May be you should try to clean your project and then use Gradle Sync to sync project?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Android Studio, then follow this link:
[Could not initialize LoginButton Facebook-sdk for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316447/could-not-initialize-loginbutton-facebook-sdk-for-android).

If you are using Eclipse, then crosscheck that you have added library project and meta data along with login activity in manifest.

Also, it may happen because of using unsupported api from android sdk. Try again using higher api level.